# How to split a string on the basis of delimiter and get the count of parts in linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, split

I have string like this

```
my/path/to/home/file.txt
```

Now I want to get the number of parts in this string on the basis of delimeter (`/`). So for the above string the answer would be `5`. I need this in my linux shell script. How to get that without using a for loop.

Comment: Indeed. But fr your question you can do: `awk -F'/' '{print NF}' <<<"$str"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It greps the delimiter, counts the occurences and adds 1 :

```
echo $(($(echo "my/path/to/home/file.txt" | grep -o "/" | wc -l)+1))
#=> 5
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F'/' '{print NF}' <<< "my/path/to/home/file.txt"
5
```

- `-F'/'`     : This will tell `awk` that fields are separate by `/` .
- `NF`        : This is the last field number.   In this case "my" is field 1,path is 2nd..... and file.txt is 5th field.
- `{print NF}`: This will print the last field number.

Comment: could you provide an explanation as to what your code actually *does*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
string="my/path/to/home/file.txt"
count="$(awk -F/ '{print $NF}' <<< "$string")"
```

`-F/` splits the string into fields based on `/` as the delimiter. `$NF` contains the number of those fields.

Answer (score 0):

only pure bash (fastest way):

```
#!/bin/bash
a=my/path/to/home/file.txt
b=${a//[^\/]}
echo $[ ${#b} +1 ]
```